# How to deal with reasking a question that was closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

This question was asked today

[Iterating through LinQ to Entities results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936503/iterating-through-linq-to-entities-results)

In it, the OP states that he asked the question the other day.

[The entity or complex type ' ' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12916080/the-entity-or-complex-type-cannot-be-constructed-in-a-linq-to-entities-query)

The original question was closed as a duplicate.  The second question would also be a duplicate, but which question should be used as the duplicate?  Should it be the original question?  Or the question the original is a duplicate of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Determine which question (and its answers) are more useful, and close the other question as a duplicate of the useful one.

In most cases, you won't have to make this determination.  If the question is truly an exact duplicate, it should be identified early,  and can be summarily closed as a duplicate of the older one. Reverse-closing a duplicate is actually fairly rare.

You can also flag for moderator attention and request that the two questions be merged.

Comment: What exactly happens when a question is merged?

Comment: Answers for a question are moved to the other question.